# Getting the Browser to login

Tags: c#, http

The Objective of the program is to Automatically log-in to my Pinboard account.  Although I seems to make contact with the /auth URI and Responds, it seems that this connection is closed or somehow not linked with the last function of opening the browser. When the browser opens, it doesn't seem to know that the program already logged-in.

Any ideas?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string FormUrl = "https://pinboard.in/auth/";
    string PinUserName = "aarondv1";
    string PinPassword = "";
    string FormParams = string.Format("username={0}&password={1}", PinUserName, PinPassword);
    string cookieHeader;

    //Three Headers to update
    //1) ContentType
    //2)Method
    //*)  Conversion from UTF-8? to ANCI2?   
            //      Not sure that its necessary, bc pinboard might use utf?? 
    //3)ContentLength

    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(FormUrl);
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.Method = "POST";

    /*Conversion*/
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(FormParams);
    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

    using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    string opend = resp.ResponseUri.ToString();

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(opend);
}
```

Comment: Cookies are browser (profile) based. Not OS based.

Answer (score 0):

When sending the request, you also need to send a cookies.

[How to: Get and Set Cookies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920298%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you call the Main method form a request ajax, you need get the browser form javascript methods (window.navigator) and send this information in the parms of Main